# Extraer números de una columna "String" en Pandas DF

Tags: python, string, regex, pandas

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame, con una columna tipo string ("Info"):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {"Date": ["2014/02/02", "2014/02/03"], 
"Info": ["Out of 78 shares traded during the session today, there were 54 increases, 9 without change and 15 decreases.", "Out of 76 shares traded during the session today, there were 60 increases, 4 without change and 12 decreases."]})
```

necesito extraer los números de "Info" y pasarlos a 4 nuevas columns en el mismo df.

Los valores de la primer fila deberían ser [78, 54, 9, 15]

Estuve tratando con lo siguiente:

```
df[["new1","new2","new3","new4"]]= df.Info.str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=True).astype(int)
```

Pero supongo que es mas complicado.

Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La siguiente línea de código te puede ayudar.

```
df["new1"], df["new2"], df["new3"], df["new4"] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: [int(s) for s in row.Info.split() if s.isdigit()] , axis=1))
```

Traería cualquier número que sea un entero, sin decimales ni que esté junto a un texto.

Como te retorna un arreglo zip lo convierte en tupla y así lo puedes asignar a las columnas en ese orden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Toma en cuenta que si no te regresa los 4 elementos enviará un error, sin embargo podrías meterlo en una función y ahí controlar cualquier excepción y regresar siempre 4 elementos

Complemento:

Para números con separadores de miles y decimales, se puede hacer de la siguiente manera tomando en cuenta (,) como separadores de miles y (.) como separador de decimales.

```
df["new1"], df["new2"], df["new3"], df["new4"] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: [s.replace(",","") for s in row.Info.split() if re.match(r'^(?:[+-]|\()?\$?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\)?$', s) is not None] , axis=1))
```

Comment: Excelente. Muchas Gracias! Estoy tratando ahora con el mismo problema, pero cuando hay números dentro del string que se encuentran con un  punto (1.000.000) separador de miles, y también para decimales separados por coma. (10,85).

Comment: yo tengo el otro formato (,) separador de miles y (.) separador de decimales, pero lo haría con la siguiente línea:  [s.replace(",","") for s in "uno 43,332.00 dos 2 , 23 tres 235".split() if re.match(r'^(?:[+-]|\()?\$?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\)?$', s) is not None]

Comment: Así quedaría al final, pero tienes que hacer el cambio de comas por puntos, porque yo tengo el otro formato, pero ya es menos :D df["new1"], df["new2"], df["new3"], df["new4"] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: [s.replace(",","") for s in row.Info.split() if re.match(r'^(?:[+-]|\()?\$?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\)?$', s) is not None] , axis=1))