# Convertir columna pandas alfanumérica (str) a números enteros (int)

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo este `DataFrame` de `pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1 texto', '22 texto', '333 texto']})
df

           a
0    1 texto
1   22 texto
2  333 texto
```

La estructura de los datos de la columna `a` es siempre la misma: un número cualquiera seguido de un espacio, seguido de un texto.

Necesito una nueva columna `b` con los valores numéricos de la columna `a`, tal que así:

```
           a    b
0    1 texto    1
1   22 texto   22
2  333 texto  333
```

He probado con la solución [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430630/extraer-n%C3%BAmeros-de-una-columna-string-en-pandas-df) propuesta, pero obtengo los valores de `b` como listas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns) una solución.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.a.str.split(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['c','d'])
df1

      c     d
0     1 texto
1    22 texto
2   333 texto

df['b'] = df1['c']
df

            a     b
0     1 texto     1
1    22 texto    22
2   333 texto   333
```